Can't enter passphrase to decrypt disk on new kernels
I have a Lenovo Ideapad 3 and Kubuntu 22.04 with an encrypted home folder. When I turn on my laptop, after GRUB, I can see the 'Enter passphrase' screen. I can start typing, but after 1-2 seconds the screen blinks and then I can't enter anything into the password field. The problem occurs on kernels 6.8.0-50 and 6.8.0-51.
I put kernel 6.8.0-49 on hold, and now I can load the system with it, but it looks like a temporary solution.
Can I fix it?

Others have reported the same problem - e.g. Can't enter passphrase for encrypted disk on splash screen. However, I haven't yet found a bug report which describes the issue with Kernels 6.8.0-50 and 6.8.0-51.

I am also facing same issue in ubuntu 24.04 with kernel 6.8.0-51 Switching to kernel 6.8.0-49 in grub menu helps.

I have the same issue with ubuntu 24.04 on my Dell Precision 5530. At the moment I am booting my old kernel.
